# transposing rows to columns in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a query that as the following rows:

```
Id     |      key          | Value 
1         Type.name.1        Value1 
2         Type.name.2        Value2
3         Type.desc.1        Desc1
4         Type.desc.2        Desc2
```

And I need a query that returns this:

```
Type.NameId  | Type.DescId
1              3
2              4
```

How can I do this in Postgres?

Comment: This is generally referred to as a "crosstab" or "pivot". I suggest searching Stack Overflow for details, there's lots out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT right(key, -10) AS name_id
   WHERE "value" ~~ 'Value%'
   ) n
FULL JOIN (
   SELECT right(key, -10) AS name_id, id AS desc_id
   WHERE "value" ~~ 'Desc%'
   ) d USING name_id;
```

Exact form depends on a lot of details missing in your question.

Your table design and naming convention give me the shivers.